# How can i append Variable name (already created) to list?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have gone through almost all answers from stack but not found answer..
Im making program to make sql insertion query..
so i have:

```
a="Aadi Aarav Aarnav Aarush Aayush Abdul Abeer Abhimanyu Abhiramnew Aditya Advaith Advay Advik Agastya Akshay Amol Anay Anirudhnew Anmol Ansh ArinArjun Arnav Aryan Atharv Avi Ayaan Ayush Ayushman Azaan Azad Daksh Darsh Dev Dev Devansh Dhruv Farhan Gautam Harsh Harshil Hredhaan Isaac IshaanJainew Jason Kabir Kalpit Karan Kiaan Krish Krishna Laksh LakshayManannew Mohammed Nachiket Naksh Nakul Neel Om Parth Pranav PraneelPranit Pratyush Rachit Raghav Ranbir Ranveer Rayaan Rehaannew Reyansh Rishi Rohan Ronith Rudranew Rushil Ryan Sai Saksham Samaksh SamarSamarth Samesh Sarthak Sathviknew Shaurya Shivansh Siddharth Tejas Vedant Veer Viaannew Vihaan Viraj Vivaan Yash Yug Zayan"
name=a.split(' ')
location="Goregaon dadar andheri vileparle santacruz london usa newYork Malad Mulund VAshi Newzealand ".split(' ')
grade="A B C D".split(' ')
query=[]
def generate(id):
    global query
    if id==1:
        query.append('[choice(name)]')
    elif id==2:
        query.append(',randint(35,99)')
    elif id==3:
        query.append(',choice(location)')
    elif id==4:
        query.append(',randint(25000,90000)')
    elif id==5:
        query.append(',choice(grade)')
    elif id==0:
        done()


def done():
    for i in range(5):
         print((query))
        #Result.insert(END,)
```

The output is::

```
['[choice(name)]', ',randint(35,99)', ',choice(location)', ',choice(location)', ',randint(25000,90000)']
['[choice(name)]', ',randint(35,99)', ',choice(location)', ',choice(location)', ',randint(25000,90000)']
['[choice(name)]', ',randint(35,99)', ',choice(location)', ',choice(location)', ',randint(25000,90000)']
['[choice(name)]', ',randint(35,99)', ',choice(location)', ',choice(location)', ',randint(25000,90000)']
['[choice(name)]', ',randint(35,99)', ',choice(location)', ',choice(location)', ',randint(25000,90000)']
```

**But I wanted output is value of that variable like random name generated how can I**

edit1:

Guys my desired output is like this..

```
insert into student values (101, 'varun', 62, 'B', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (102, 'nana', 46, 'C', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (103, 'varun', 56, 'A', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (104, 'rajkumar', 81, 'D', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (105, 'varun', 73, 'A', 'malad') ;
insert into student values (106, 'rajkumar', 49, 'A', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (107, 'rajkumar', 37, 'D', 'malad') ;
insert into student values (108, 'deepika', 30, 'C', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (109, 'varun', 37, 'D', 'goregaon') ;
```

i have a gui program
like this..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLwIc.png)

so the number of variables are not fixed/..
when user click on the buttons it make  list of variables..
in list
then i want to iterate over this..
hope u get my problem,,

Comment: Can you show what your actual desired output should look like?

Comment: `query.append('[choice(name)]')` appends the literal string `'[choice(name)]'`, because **that's what you told it to do**.  If you want to randomly choose one item from the list, use `random.choice(name)`.

Comment: my desired output is insert into student values (101, 'varun', 62, 'B', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (102, 'nana', 46, 'C', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (103, 'varun', 56, 'A', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (104, 'rajkumar', 81, 'D', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (105, 'varun', 73, 'A', 'malad') ;
insert into student values (106, 'rajkumar', 49, 'A', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (107, 'rajkumar', 37, 'D', 'malad') ;
insert into student values (108, 'deepika', 30, 'C', 'vashi') ;
insert into student values (109, 'varun', 37, 'D', 'goregaon')

Comment: check question im edieted

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly get that output from anything like your code. There's no way that either `randint(35, 99)` or `randint(25000,90000)` or any of your other values is going to give you sequential numbers starting from 101. I can't see how you're going to get two locations by choosing one location and one name. And I don't know how you expect Python to guess at the right output order if you don't even know it.

Comment: no u didnt get..that was just sample...fro the output of 101 etc i m gonna give i value iterations...i have variabels in list i want values o fthat vraiabkles just...and it is considering as strings but  want o teke consider as list

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of an expression, just use the expression; don't put it in quotes:

```
query.append([choice(name)])
# ...
query.append(randint(35, 99))
# etc.
```

---

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the commas there. If you really want a list of the string representations of your values with commas before them, you can use string formatting for that:

```
query.append(f',{randint(35, 99)}')
```

This may look similar to what you're doing, but there are two major differences.

First, the `f` prefix before a string means this is a string formatting expression (aka f-string), where the bits inside `{…}` are evaluated.

And second, the `randint(35, 99)` expression is one of those bits inside `{…}`, so it gets evaluated as a value, which is then formatted to a string and inserted into the template.

So, while the `randint(35, 99)` in your original code meant the literal characters `r`, `a`, `n`, etc., the `{randint(35, 99)}` inside an f-string depends on what you get from calling `randint(35, 99)`—for example, it may end up meaning the characters `4` and `2`.

But if you didn't want those commas in your values, all of this is overcomplicating things; just append the values themselves, as I said at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but I'll give it my best shot. It looks like you are creating a data structure to store information about students. There are two better ways to do this. Either with a dictionary or an object. I will go through the object method.

You want to create a student class to contain your data.

```
class Student:
    def ___init___(self, name, letter_grade, score, location):
        self.name = name
        self.letter_grade = letter_grade
        self.score = score
        self.location = location
```

Using this data structure you can store your students within a list, and call information about them. Here is an example of that.

```
class Student:
    def ___init___(self, name, letter_grade, score, location):
        self.name = name
        self.letter_grade = letter_grade
        self.score = score
        self.location = location

students = []
students.append(Student("varun", "A", 67, "vashi")
```

This will store a student in the students list with a name, grade, and location. To return the information about them, you need to specifically call it.

```
print(students[0].name)
```

will return "varun"

so if you wanted to call all information at once about a student you could do something similar to this

```
for student in students:
    print("insert into student values: ", student.name, student.letter_grade, student.score, student.location)
```

Comment: Thank you ,your right...im. making data structure for students data ,,actually if you check the question you can see there is image file that images have button if user selects name then random name should be added but I want n number of data so I m cresting a list in which I have variables like name,number etc which are added by users from GUI program in image so then I want to exedxure that list n number of times so it wil create a number of SQL queries...yes I wanted a SQL queries.....generator only simple one that insert into values....etc..so..I hope you get it